# How to Improve Data Scraping Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have below code, which fetch data from a Intranet. But its taking more time to fetch data.can someone help me to modify the code to increase the performance.
Thanks In Advance

Note-I haven't posted URL as it is clients website. Sorry about that.

```
Sub FetchData() 
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim myStr As String
On Error Resume Next

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'SetBrowser
  IE.Visible = False

IE.navigate "URL" 'Open website
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set Doc = IE.Document

Doc.getElementById("tbxUserID").Value = InputBox("Please Enter Your ID")
Doc.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = InputBox("Please Enter Your                     
Password")
Doc.getElementById("BtnLogin").Click
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.navigate "URL"
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Dim LastRow As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet
LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rowNo = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
  For rowNo = 2 To LastRow
Doc.getElementById("txtField1").Value =         
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rowNo).Value
Doc.getElementById("CtrlQuickSearch1_imgBtnSumbit").Click
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

strVal1 = Doc.querySelectorAll("span")(33).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowNo).Value = strVal1
strVal2 = Doc.querySelectorAll("span")(35).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & rowNo).Value = strVal2

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code is working, please consider posting to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

Can't guarantee this will run. Points to note:

1. Use of `Worksheets` collection
2. Use of `Option Explicit` - this means you then have to use the right datatype throughout. Currently you have undeclared variables and, for example, rowNo is used as a Long and as a range.
3. Removal of `On Error Resume Next`
4. Putting all worksheets into variables
5. Placement of values into array and looping array to get id values. Looping sheet is expensive
6. Use of early binding and adding class to InternetExplorer
7. Assumption that after login a new url present and that you need to navigate back to that before each new loop value
8. Removal of hungarian notation
9. Ids are fastest selector method so no improvement there
10. With your css type selectors, e.g. `.document.querySelectorAll("span")(33)`, you might seek whether there is a single node short selector that can be used, rather than using nodeList

VBA:

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub FetchData()
    Dim ie As Object, ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim lastRow As Long, wks As Worksheet, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer        'SetBrowser
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wks = ActiveSheet                        '<==use explicit sheet name if possible
    lastRow = wks.Cells(wks.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    loopvalues = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value)

    With ie

        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 "URL"                         'Open website

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("tbxUserID").Value = InputBox("Please Enter Your ID")
        .document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = InputBox("Please Enter Your Password")
        .document.getElementById("BtnLogin").Click

        While .Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim newURL As String, val1 As String, val2 As String
        newURL = .document.URL

        For i = LBound(loopvalues) To UBound(loopvalues)

            .document.getElementById("txtField1").Value = loopvalues(i)
            .document.getElementById("CtrlQuickSearch1_imgBtnSumbit").Click

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            val1 = .document.querySelectorAll("span")(33).innerText
            ws.Range("B" & i).Value = val1
            val2 = .document.querySelectorAll("span")(35).innerText
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = val2

            .Navigate2 newURL

            While .Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.. i am getting Run time Error '424' on line ".Document.getElementById("txtField1").Value = loopvalues(i)"  and  where i should put my 2nd URL in the code? in "newURL = .Document.URL" line?

Comment: You mat need a timed loop (first try adding a wait before that line or stepping through with F8 - does the 424 go away? If not, step through with F8 and check the value of loopValues(i) in locals window.

Comment: its taking A1 value as "loopValues(i)" .  actually, after that login page again i have to navigate to the same website with different page which has elements "txtField1" and CtrlQuickSearch1_imgBtnSumbit. in code where i should put the 2nd URL?

Comment: Where i say .navigate2 newUrl

Comment: Getting Variable Not Defined on line " ws.Range("B" & rowNo).Value = val1"  and  Automation Error on line "val1 = .Document.querySelectorAll("span")(33).innerText"

Comment: rowNo should be i instead. I have just edited change. Sorry.

Comment: Getting Runtime Error -2147352319(80020101)  Automation Error on line "val1 = .Document.querySelectorAll("span")(33).innerText"   any help on this?

Comment: Was this line working before? Can you do Dim a As Object: Set a = ie.document.querySelectorAll("span").item(33)

Comment: One last thing, how to skip if the result is null and continue the execution?

Comment: Getting  Compile Error "Variable Not Defined"  on line "If not .document.querySelectorAll(“span”).length = 0 then"   its highlighting "Span".

Comment: If not .document.querySelectorAll("span").length = 0    < try that

Comment: tried "If not .document.querySelectorAll("span").length = 0 " then Getting Compile Error "Variable Not Defined"

Comment: not from that code you won't. Are you sure you have the ie object? ie.document.querySelectorAll("span").Length = 0

Comment: Dim ie As InternetExplorer... there is no ie as object

Comment: I meant you have written as ie.document.querySelectorAll("span").Length = 0 . Write like that by copying it from here and then tell me if there error occurs and on which line. I have written this hundreds of times. It is correct. Also, be sure you have Option Explicit as the first line in your module and that your code is in a standard module.

Comment: Hi, Used"ie.document.querySelectorAll("span").Length = 0 " and there Option Explicit is on top of the code... Actually there are some invalid input numbers for which the "span" will not be returned.... i am getting Run time Error "Object Required" on Line Set a = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("span").Item(33)

Comment: Because you need to use the If statement and put that line in the Else.  If ie.Document.querySelectorAll("span")  = 0 Then "do something here" : Else : Set a = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("span").Item(33) : End If

Comment: No luck  with above code. getting same error  "Object Required" on Line Set a = ie.Document.querySelectorAll("span").Item(33). is it possible to have some error handler?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the length.  Test if the length is >=34 before trying to access.

Comment: when i place cursor on length in debug mode, it doesnt show any value

Comment: @ QHrr i added  Error Handler On Error GoTo ErrHandler:                     "ErrHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            val1 = "Invalid Input"
            ws.Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value = val1
            val2 = "Invalid Input"
            ws.Range("C" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value = val2
          Resume Next                                                                                                        the code is working totally fine as per my requirement. Thanks a lot for your time and helping me to learn many new things. Have a great day Sir. Thanks again.